# Unusual behavior with UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm getting some unusual behavior with `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. The first swipe is detected correctly but the second swipe is not. Then the third swipe is detected correctly but the fourth is not etc. I have two swipe gesture recognizers, one for left and one for right. Here is the code:

**.h file**

```
- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
```

**.m file**

```
- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        NSLog(@"you swiped left");
        [self spinSunCounterClockwise];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"you swiped right");
        [self spinSunClockwise];
    }

}
```

So, for example, if i *swipe left* the first time, `spinSunCounterClockwise` is called, but if i *swipe left again*, `spinSunClockwise` is called.

Another example is, if i *swipe left* the first time, `spinSunCounterClockwise` is called. If i *swipe right*, `spinSunCounterClockwise` is called again.

Any help please?

**EDIT 1:** One of the spinning methods

```
-(void) spinSunCounterClockwise
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
        imgSun.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imgSun.transform, 3.142);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

Comment: What do `spinSunCounterClockwise` and `spinSunClockwise` do? Do they rotate the view that you've added the gesture recognizers to?

Comment: Yes, i'll update the OP with one of the methods, the other method having the minus value for the degree. I also get the wrong `NSLog` message on every odd swipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rotate your view by 180° (btw, you should use `M_PI` instead of `3.142`), the view is upside down afterwards, so what was previously left is now right and vice-versa.

So when you swipe left the first time, the second time a left swipe (from your perspective) is actually recognized as a right swipe, while a right swipe is actually a left swipe, which explains the the behavior you've observed.

After two gestures (360° rotation), your view is in its original orientation again, so the recognition is "normal" again for the third gesture.

Comment: Thanks. I have two questions: 1. if i want to rotate it 360degs what value do i use (`2*M_PI` doesn't seem to work). 2. what would you suggest i do if I want to rotate 180degs but still want my swipes to work correctly.

Comment: 1. You'll find lots of posts regarding that topic on SO, just search for something like "360 uiview", most answers seem to involve using `CAAnimation`. 2. You could check if the view is rotated (e.g. using `CGAffineTransformIsIdentity`) and perform the opposite action in that case.

Comment: Yeah, i've searched for that alright - `CAAnimation` isn't something i really want to implement here so i decided to rotate by 179.999 degrees and then another 179.999 degrees upon completion. Thanks again for your help.